# Android Studio - Support Multiple Screens

Tags: android-screen-support

I'm trying to support multiple screen sizes in my app... I added this to my Manifest.xml:

```
`<supports-screens
 android:normalScreens="true"    
 android:smallScreens="true"    
 android:largeScreens="true"    
 android:xlargeScreens="true"    
 android:anyDensity="true"/>`
```

I also added different layout sizes and densities:

layout-small
layout-large
layout-normal
layout-xlarge

drawable-ldpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhpi

My layout-normal is currently set on Nexus 4:  [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fscnU.png)

Now it's set on Nexus One: [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Skl.png)

How can I set the elements to scale automatically?

Comment: You don't need those screen sizes in the manifest.  They all default to true.  As for elements scaling-  setting their width and height to wrap_content or match_parent will scale them.  Beyond that it depends on what specific effect you want to get on them.

Comment: You don't need the `<supports-screens.../>` tag, all of them are true by default. Your layout is not defined properly. You need to share the layout file here.

Comment: Is there any other way  to scale  the elements automatically without  setting  their height  and width to wrap_content or match_parent?

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any other way to scale the elements automatically without setting their height and width to wrap_content or match_parent?*

of course you can do it programmatically

example:
I defined Simple Object `ImageSize` like this:

```
public class ImageSize {
    private float width;
    private float height;

    public float getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(float height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

then I created a layout which contains Image(another layout) in it

```
final LinearLayout sellCarImage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sellCarImage);
final RelativeLayout sellCarLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sellCarLayout);
```

then I've calculated width and height to scale view sizes based on image real size:

```
 ImageSize img = new ImageSize();
 img = getImageSize(R.drawable.indeximage5, MainActivity.this);
 int sellCarWidth = sellCarLayout.getWidth();
 int sellCarHeight = (int) ((sellCarWidth * img.getHeight()) / img.getWidth());
```

and programmatically set width and height:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sellCarImageIconParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(sellCarWidth, sellCarHeight);
//sellCarImageIconParams.setMargins(marg, 0, marg, 0);
sellCarImage.setLayoutParams(sellCarImageIconParams);
sellCarImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indeximage5);
```

here is getImageSize

```
 public ImageSize getImageSize(int resource, Context ctx) {
        ImageSize imageSize = new ImageSize();
        BitmapFactory.Options dimensions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        dimensions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), resource, dimensions);
        imageSize.setHeight(dimensions.outHeight);
        imageSize.setWidth(dimensions.outWidth);
        return imageSize;
    }
```

it's better to put them in:

```
    sellCarLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
           //here
        });
    }
```

I hope it helps